# How to copy a files from host to a created directory?

Tags: perl, scp

I am trying to copy a files from host to created directory. Here is my script:

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Net::SCP::Expect;

my $filename;
GetOptions(
    "file=s" => \$filename
);
my $src_path="/";
my $directory;
open(INBOX, "<$filename") or die "Can't open $filename\n";

while(<INBOX>) {
    chomp;
    my @arr = split(/:/);
    my $host=$arr[0];
    my $username=$arr[1];
    my $password=$arr[2];

    sub main {
        my $directory = "temp";
        unless(-e $directory or mkdir $directory) {
            die "Unable to create $directory";
        }
    }

    main();
    print "Copying from $host \n";
    my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(
        host     => $host,
        user     => $username,
        password => $password,
    );
    $scpe->scp($host . ":" . $src_path, $directory);
```

But here I am unable to move or copy a files from host to the created    directory called temp. Can you help me in this regard in Perl?

Comment: What happens when you run your program? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: As you can see I tried to improve the formatting of your answer. It seems this is only part of the code or there is a closing curly brace `}` missing at the end of it. Try to keep your code indented correctly as you'll see mistakes easily. Use can use [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltidy) which will safely and automatically pretty-format your code.

Comment: Do you have checked the error code returned by `scp` function?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing strange things with scoping here:

In your sub, which - strange enough - is called "main", you declare a **locally scoped** variable $directory and assign "temp" to it.

However the variable $directory declared in the main program in line 10 stays empty - but that's the one used in the scp.

I would suggest to change this

```
sub main {
    my $directory = "temp";
    unless(-e $directory or mkdir $directory) {
        die "Unable to create $directory";
    }
}
main();
```

into that:

```
$directory = "temp";
unless(-e $directory or mkdir $directory) {
    die "Unable to create $directory";
}
```